# How to use kbn-top-nav menu in a new app?

Tags: kibana-5

*Kibana 5.2.2*

In my Kibana app, I want to use the kbn-top-nav menu, like it is [done in timelion app](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/src/core_plugins/timelion/public/index.html#L3).

I added the line to my template substituting only the name arg:

```
<kbn-top-nav name="myappname" config="topNavMenu"></kbn-top-nav>
```

In the controller, I added the config array:

```
  $scope.topNavMenu = [ 
    {   
      key: 'home',
      description: 'Home',
      run: function () { kbnUrl.change('/'); }
    },  
    {   
      key: 'about',
      description: 'About',
      run: function () { kbnUrl.change('/about'); }
    }   
  ];
```

But I don't see any menu on the top. How to use kbn-top-nav properly?

**Update**:
I imported the directive in my app.js `import 'ui/kbn_top_nav';` and now I see a raw menu list without any styling. How to get styles properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll also need `require('ui/autoload/styles');`